# user.getSolutions() or Solution.getSolutionsFrom(user_id)?

Tags: oop, model-view-controller

I have two model classes: `User` and `Solution`, and I want to implement a method to get all solutions submitted by a user. I can make it an instance method in `User` (e.g., `user.getSolutions()`, or I can make it a static method in `Solution` (e.g., `Solution.getSolutionsFrom(user_id)`. I am not sure which design is better. `user.getSolutions()` feels more nature, but the implementation will suffer from the [Feature Envy Smell](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FeatureEnvySmell), as the only thing that the method need from `User` is the user_id, and the rest of logic are dealing with `Solution`. Also, if I only have user_id, I have to construct a dummy user instance just to call `user.getSolutions()`, that feels wrong too.

Answer (score 1):

I would not put the static method in the Solution model, but create a a SolutionsManager class instead.
The model should not have any logic inside but the setting and getting of properties.

```
public class SolutionManager {
       public List<Solution> getSolutions(int userId) {
               ...
       }
}
```

Comment: Any benefits of having a SolutionManager? In the MVC of Ruby On Rails for example, models (Active Record) provides tons of ways to access data, not just getters and setters. Getting solutions from a user is just a way to access data.

Comment: Well, the most prominent benefit is that you are separating concerns. The model should not be aware of how it will be stored or accessed. It is just a representation of a business object.

I would have a Data Access Object (DAO) for CRUD operations on the database, and use the repository pattern to make an even more abstract layer of access.
The repository should be capable of retrieving all the solutions for a given User ID.

I will, then, inject the repository onto the SolutionManager, and the getSolutions method of the solution manager will just be a call to the repository

Comment: In an MVC architecture, where would you put SolutionManager if it's not a model?

Comment: Well, you rather take it as an extension for the model, without the Solution model, the SolutionManager would not exist, so i'd place it in the Domain or Model layer.
Consider it like a business logic encapsulation class.

I find it more mantainable to have the an entity model with no logic (which is the one that will be persisted), and a manager class that will manage the access to the model or perform business logic on it